# how do i write into RDP file with powershell script or python script

Tags: powershell, automation

how can i add to the file?

```
ls "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\*.rdp" -recurse | %{
     (gc $_ ) -replace "use multimon:i:0", "use multimon:i:1" |
     set-content $_.FullName -force
}
```

I don't have these lines below because I download the RDP file from my work website.

i want to add this lines to the RDP file:

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
desktopwidth:i:800
desktopheight:i:600
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
```

Comment: It is unclear what you now have in your RDP file and what you would like to add. Do you mean to add all the settings you show us? What to do with settings already present in your own rdp file(s) ? should they be overwritten with the values from work?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two questions here:

1. how do I update a certain setting in an RDP file
2. How do I add settings from one rdp file to an existing file

**PowerShell solution**

To answer both, I would create a small helper function to read in all the settings from an RDP file as **object** array, so the contents would be easy to manipulate.

Please read all the inline comments in the code below:

```
function ConvertFrom-Rdp {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path
    )
    # read the file (except empty or whitespace-only lines) and parse each line
    Get-Content -Path $Path | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
        $name, $type, $value = ($_ -split ':', 3).Trim()
        # Type: 'i' --> Integer, 's' --> string
        [PsCustomObject]@{ Name = $name; Type = $type; Value = $value }
    }
}

# read the settings from the work RDP file as array of PsCustomObjects
$rdpWork = ConvertFrom-Rdp -Path 'X:\Somewhere\work.rdp'
# create a list to store the current settings and add new ones from work
$rdpList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
# find and loop over the RDP files
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop' -Filter '*.rdp' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $rdpFile = $_.FullName
    # store the current settings in the list
    $rdpList.AddRange(( ConvertFrom-Rdp -Path $rdpFile))
    foreach ($settingFromWork in $rdpWork) {
        # try and find the setting with the same name in the users rdp file
        $existing = $rdpList | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $settingFromWork.Name }

        ####################################################################
        # you make the choice here to either only add new settings to the
        # users rdp file or to overwrite existing settings with values from
        # the work rdp file
        ####################################################################

        # Option 1: overwrite with what you have with what is in $rdpWork ?
        if ($existing) {
            $existing.Type  = $settingFromWork.Type
            $existing.Value = $settingFromWork.Value
        }
        else { $rdpList.Add($settingFromWork) }
    
        # Option 2: keep the setting from the current file and only add new setting from work
        # if (!$existing) { $rdpList.Add($settingFromWork) }
    }

    # next, look for the 'use multimon' setting in the list and force that to value 1
    $existing = $rdpList | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'use multimon' }
    if ($existing) { 
        # update the existing setting
        $existing.Type = 'i'; $existing.Value = 1 } 
    else {
        # setting was not found, add new
        $rdpList.Add([PsCustomObject]@{Name = 'use multimon'; Type = 'i'; Value = 1})
    }

    # finally, write out the updated file
    # keep a copy of the original file first ?
    $backupName = '{0}.bak' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($rdpFile)
    Rename-Item -Path $rdpFile -NewName $backupName -Force

    $rdpList | ForEach-Object {
        '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $_.Name, $_.Type, $_.Value
    } | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path $rdpFile

    # clear the list for the next file
    $rdpList.Clear()
}
```

Note: In order to not change the source rdp file you have downloaded from work, store this in a **different** path than where the files to update are.